# How can i have pick only date from datetmepicker in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, datepicker

I want to pick only date but it is asking me to select time also.

I'm using the following code,

**view.tpl.html**

```
<div class='input-group date' id='datePicker'>
   <input type='text' id="date" class="form-control"            
 ng-model="model.date" date-picker required />
   <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
   </span>
</div>
```

**directive.js**

```
angular.module('directives.date-picker', [])
.directive('datePicker',['$filter', '$window', function($filter, $window) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {

    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        var datePicker = document.getElementById('datePicker');

        angular.element(datePicker).datetimepicker({
            format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
            showMeridian: true,
            autoclose: true
        });
   angular.element($window).bind('keydown', function(event) {
            if (event.keyCode === 27) {
                angular.element(datePicker).datetimepicker('hide');

            }
        }); 

    }
};
  }]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `minView` property to the `datetimepicker` object like

`minView` is the lowest view that the datetimepicker should show.

```
    angular.element(datePicker).datetimepicker({
        format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
        showMeridian: true,
        autoclose: true,
        minView : 1 //for day view minimum
    });
```

- 0 or 'hour' for the hour view
- 1 or 'day' for the day view
- 2 or 'month' for month view (the default)
- 3 or 'year' for the 12-month overview
- 4 or 'decade' for the 10-year overview.

[Documentation](http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) here If this is the `datetimepicker` you are using.

Hope it helps